# Старшие версии Android телефонов не видят BLE устройство

Tags: android-studio, esp32, bluetooth-le

Есть публичный проект под Android Studio - [BluetoothLeGatt](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt), который обнаруживает Bluetooth Low Energy устройства и показывает их службы и характеристики. Также есть проект для ESP32 под Arduino IDE, тоже публичный, находится в `Примеры/ESP BLE Arduino/BLE_server_multiconnect` - здесь создаётся сервер, в нём создаётся служба, характеристика, и запускается `advertising`.

Я собрал `apk` файл и установил в телефон с версией Android 4.4.1 - всё прекрасно работает - приложение показывает найденное устройство "ESP32" и можно посмотреть его службы и характеристики.

Телефоны же с более молодой версией Android (8.1 и 9.0) не видят устройство при сканировании. При этом если зайти в системные настройки телефона и устройства Bluetooth, то там устройство ESP32 будет видно.

Понимаю, что-то не так с проектом на Android Studio. В файле AndroidManifest.xml все нужные разрешения установлены.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Как решить проблему, чтоб и на младших моделях Android устройство определялось?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Необходимо после первого запуска приложения на телефоне перейти в `Системные настройки телефона/Приложения/Все приложения/Наше приложение/Разрешения приложений/` и здесь включить определение местоположения.

Comment: а почему не использовать системный запрос разрешения как например описано здесь - https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions ?